# sound conversion from .mp3 or any suitable format to MIDI

Tags: java, android, midi

Suppose I am able to record sound from Android's Sound Recoder API. Is it possible to convert sound of this format to MIDI codec from which i can finally extract frequencies or pitches so that scores can be rendered on Screen. If so i'll be interested in the source of material.Help appreciated.

Comment: I am in dead need help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Music Transcription of Wav files in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919335/music-transcription-of-wav-files-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

You are seeking to convert an audio waveform, which is a sequence of voltages at say 44 kHz, to MIDI, which is a sequence of note-on and note-off digital instrument commands with something like millisecond timing, and then to a musical score, which is a high-level, abstract representation of music.

Note that these are more like recognition steps than format conversion steps. The first step is analogous to taking a highway photo and recognizing vector graphics shapes, while the second step is analogous to taking those shapes and recognizing letters on signs, sign shapes, road lanes, and vehicles. These are doable within constraints but not easy and probably not entirely automatic to get good results.

A web search found https://www.ableton.com/en/articles/audio-to-midi-tips-and-tricks/ for one.

Last I heard, there are good results for the second step in the case where the musician picks the tempo, time signature, and key; then the program plays a click track and musician plays on a keyboard in sync with that click track; then the musician cleans up the result and makes choices like tied notes.

Comment: I understand the workflow but can't get started. all links i found googling produced results parts of the result not all of it completely

Comment: That's because your goal requires advancing the state of the art. It's a research topic, esp. if you want to do it without a lot of human guidance.

Comment: It is something like to reconstruct Mona Lisa with triangles. In fact, there is such a project called Genetic Programming: Evolution of Mona Lisa. In a similar way MP3->MIDI can be calculated.