# Is there a paper or model about detecting whether musical instrument playing right note or not?

Tags: machine-learning, audio, deep-learning, detection

I want to create a model that can detecting whether musical instrument play right note or not.

Example: provide mp3 file and musician are playing in piano. How to check the musician play right note according to mp3 file.

I had search GG but not found anything related.

Comment: Maybe try the [Signal Processing Stack](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just compare raw audio files directly, as you probably know. Let's break the problem down into subproblems that you might be able to solve.

- Decode your audio into uncompressed PCM.
- Process your PCM audio into a standard format that consists of a series of "notes", like MIDI.
- Align your sequences somehow, perhaps using something like [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping), which would allow you to measure insertions/deletions as you run the algorithm.
- Count differences between your sequences and quantify error by some metric.

I would recommend you forget about mp3s to start, and instead find some free MIDI files online (or make your own). Test your algorithm by taking your reference MIDI file, modifying it in various ways, and then running your algorithm against the orginal and each modified version.

If you get that far and are happy with the results, then move onto the conversion problem (audio file -> MIDI). Of course, you don't have to use MIDI, you could design your own format; it's up to you how to tackle this. A WAV file is usually just a header + PCM, so you could look at this:

[wav-to-midi conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126193/wav-to-midi-conversion)